Getting an error while executing test case in React Vite
I am using React with Vite. And this is the piece of code for which I am writing test cases -
import { otelLogError } from 'instrumentation-logger';

const {
    data: notificationResponse,
    error,
    isError,
    isFetching,
  } = useGetNotificationsQuery({
    name: selectedEvent,
    page: pageNumberValue,
    limit: pageSizeVal,
  });

useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      otelLogError('Error fetching notification data', isError);
      setErrorBanner(isError);
    }
  }, [isError]);

Test cases code -
vi.mock('instrumentation-logger', () => ({
  otelLogError: vi.fn(),
}));

it('throws OTELLogError when error is true', () => {
    const initialState = {
      [notificationApi.reducerPath]: {
        error: 'Test error',
      },
    };
    setup(initialState);
    expect(otelLogError).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

I am getting this error -
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once
I have read the documentation but I did not understand what else is missing.
